# Goodness-of-fit test for nominal data?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have asked 40 people to choose their favourite colour from a possible 4 (Red, Blue, Green & White), and their favourite football team from a possible 4 (Liverpool, Chelsea, Plymouth Argyle and Leeds), to see if there is a correlation between the two.

How can I test for correlation given my data is nominal?

Comment: You probably shouldn't ask the same question twice: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100649/what-statistical-test-to-use-chi2-or-t?noredirect=1#comment4330901_2100649

Comment: Have you tried asking Google? "[How do I find correlation measure between two nominal variables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51875)" on the stats site is literally the top hit.

Comment: I really do not follow how a Chi squared will work given it does not take into account which agree, but instead the amounts. I do not care about the amounts of "Leeds fans" for example, only if they said "Leeds & White"

Comment: Could someone please do an example if for example 30 agree and 10 disagree.

Comment: Please withdraw your previous attempt, which had distracting flaws. This is a much clearer form of the question.

Comment: Happy to do that Bruce. the comments in that post did help this question.

Comment: No doubt. But in retrospect, there is probably not much there of use to future visitors, given that the current form is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using 'correlation' in a colloquial, rather than
a technical sense. Here is a test of hypothesis based on your Comment, with a bit of
rationalization for it.

By random chance, the probability of agreement would be 1/3. So the
null distribution is $X \sim Binom(40, 1/3),$ where $X$ counts
agreements. If you have $X = 30$ agreements, then that's more than
the 'expected' $E(X) = np = 40(1/3) = 13.33.$

The P-value of a test
would be $P(X \ge 30) \approx 0.$  If colors choices were at random
without regard to team favoritism, it would be almost impossible
to get 30 'agreements'. Probability computations below are from
R statistical software:

```
 1 - pbinom(29, 40, 1/3)             # 'pbinom' is binomial CDF
 ## 8.474878e-08
 x = 30:40;  sum(dbinom(x, 40, 1/3)) # 'dbinom' is binomial PDF
 ## 8.474878e-08
```

And from Minitab 17:

```
 Test and CI for One Proportion 

 Test of p = 0.3333 vs p > 0.3333

                                              Exact
 Sample   X   N  Sample p  95% Lower Bound  P-Value  
 1       30  40  0.750000         0.612940    0.000
```

The interpretation of the one-sided 95% CI is that you have 95%
'confidence' that the true proportion $p$ of 'agreements' exceeds $0.61.$

*Note:* One might use a normal approximation to get the P-value. Since it turns
out to be so small, an approximation would be OK. But in general, for
$n$ as small as 40, I think exact computation is better.

*Addendum: (response to Comment)* Here are computations in R for your
proposed chi-squared test. You have 2 cells, hence df = 2-1 = 1.
The chi-squared goodness-of-fit statistic is $Q = \sum_{i=1}^2 (X-E)^2/E,$
where X's are observed counts and E's are expected counts. $Q \sim Chisq(1),$
provided $E_i > 5.$ The computed value is $Q = 31.25;$ the 5% critical value
is $q^* = 3.8415$. Reject 'fit' because $Q > q^*;$ P-value of this
approximate test is essentially $0.$

```
Obs = c(30, 10); prob = c(1/3, 2/3)
n = 40;  Exp = n*prob
Q = sum((Obs-Exp)^2/Exp);  Q
## 31.25
qchisq(.95, 1)     # critical value
## 3.841459
1 - pchisq(Q, 1)   # aprx P-value
## 2.268475e-08
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, you have sparked something though, could I just do a (one sample?) chi squared with a 1x2 table of "Match" and "No Match" and the observed values, and run a chi squared?

Comment: Thanks bruce, could I just ask how you get 1/4 and 3/4 in this tets, but 1/3 and 2/3 in the biniomial?

Comment: Memory lapse. Fixing it.

Comment: Will do, But I do not understand wether to use 1/3 or 1/4 for the probability

Comment: As commented above, 1/4 was a mistake (fixed now). Three 'colors', three teams: randomly chosen probability of match is 1/3.